# Updating dictionaries in one list from dictionaries in another list without matching keys in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge

I want to update the dictionaries in list1 with the key pairs from list2 and I'm really struggling to find the solution.

```
list1 = [{"A":1, "B":2, "C":3},{"A":1, "B":2, "C":3}]
list2 = [{"D":4,"E":5,"F":6},{"D":4,"E":5,"F":6}]
```

desired outcome

```
[{"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3, "D": 4, "E": 5, "F": 6}, {A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3, "D": 4, "E": 5, "F": 6}]
```

Comment: `[x | y for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]` (requires Python >= 3.9).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the output you want by iterating over the dictionaries in `list1` and updating them with the key-value pairs from the dictionaries in `list2`.

```
list1 = [{"A":1, "B":2, "C":3},{"A":1, "B":2, "C":3}]
list2 = [{"D":4,"E":5,"F":6},{"D":4,"E":5,"F":6}]

for i in range(len(list1)):
    list1[i].update(list2[i])

print(list1)
```

Output

```
[{'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4, 'E': 5, 'F': 6}, {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4, 'E': 5, 'F': 6}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function of Python to get the output.
Try this:

```
for dict1, dict2 in zip(list1, list2):
    dict1.update(dict2)

print(list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code.

```
list1 = [{"A":1, "B":2, "C":3},{"A":1, "B":2, "C":3}]
list2 = [{"D":4,"E":5,"F":6},{"D":4,"E":5,"F":6}]


list1[0].update(list2[0])
list1[1].update(list2[1])

print(list1)
```

Output

[{'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4, 'E': 5, 'F': 6}, {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4, 'E': 5, 'F': 6}]